# Что такое "главный редактор" на странице голосов в панели модератора?

Tags: поддержка, локализация, инструменты-модератора, голосование

Не понимаю, что за тип голоса "главный редактор". К тому же, скорее всего перевод кривой. Вот мои 19 плюсов и 6 непонятно чего в пользу другого участника:

[image: Скриншот]

Comment: А тип «против» тоже можно таким способом посмотреть? Или только «за»?

Comment: @Bharatha, за, против, принятый ответ и вот эта штука. Других пока не встречал. Но это только статистика, к конкретным голосам у модераторов доступа нет.

Answer (score 5):

В оригинале там вообще:

> approve suggested edit"

Т.е, это принятые правки.

Comment: Эм.. Всё равно непонятно. Кто правил и кто принимал? Что если в очереди проверок за правку голосовало несколько человек? И ещё, а по отклонённым аналог есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy кто-то предложил правку к твоему сообщению, ты принял её. Я так понимаю, это оно и есть.

Comment: @Suvitruf-AndreiApanasik, скорее жал: "Принять и улучшить"

Comment: Тот кто-то, с чьей страницы я сделал сокращённый скриншот? Что-то маловероятно.

Comment: @Qwertiy лучше на MSE спросить)

Comment: @Grundy, ох и Grundy, даже такие вещи знает, которые ему недоступны! Молодец!

Comment: @Bharatha, Grundy доступно все (¬‿¬ )

Answer (score 1):

Участник @Suvitruf уже дал правильный ответ, но поскольку не все могут это понять, то я напишу подробно:

Итак, на английском SO это означает `«approve suggested edit»`, что в переводе на русский язык означает `«принять предложенную правку»`. @Grundy в своём отзыве к ответу @Suvitruf написал когда это случается – а именно при принятии предложенной правки через `«Принять и улучшить»`. Поскольку при этом дополнительных голосов для принятия предложенной правки не требуется, то и называется это `«Главный редактор»`.

Comment: По-прежнему непонятно, где кто. Вот есть _я_ и есть _участник,_ на странице которого написано, что он _получил от_ меня 6 штук _«принять предложенную правку»._ 1. Кто делал правки, а кто принимал? 2. Надо ли было, чтобы он принимал их самостоятельно, или достаточно очереди проверок? 3. Считаются ли правки, сделанные без необходимости проверки (т. е. при достаточной репутации)? 4. Что такое _237_ в общем количестве таких голосов?

Comment: @Qwertiy, 1. Делал правки тот в отношении кого ты смотрел и тогда, когда не имел права (либо и сейчас не имеет) на правки (репутация < 2000), а принимал ты, когда нажимал «Принять и улучшить». Если просто принимал (без улучшений), то это не в счёт в данном случае. 2. Участники с репутацией < 2000 не могут принимать правки, они их могут только предлагать.3. Этот вопрос я не понял - он непонятно написан. 4. Для ответа на этот вопрос я должен быть бы модератором. Если бы я хотя бы знал кто этот участник, то можно было хотя бы предположить.

Comment: @Qwertiy, возможно 237 раз ты принимал правки от всех участников когда нажимал «Принять и улучшить», а 6 раз только по отношению к этому участнику.

Comment: @Qwertiy, почему не отвечаешь?

Comment: Потому что не знаю, как это проверить...

Comment: @Qwertiy, либо перечитай ещё раз мои объяснения, либо покажи мой ответ Николасу – он точно знает.

Comment: Объяснения я прочитал, но я пока не придумал, как проверить их правильность.